# How to create sub collection on document Firebase Function Express?

Tags: node.js, firebase, express, google-cloud-firestore

The below code snippet is how I implement to create a sub collection of `likes` under the document for PostID. I receive an error of 404 not found. I have read a documentation where collection can be created if there is a document under the collection.

Post -> PostId -> Likes

```
exports.updateLike = function (req, res) {

    const postId = req.params.postId;
    const userId = req.params.userId;

    // return 404 not found 
    db.collection("posts").doc(postId).collection("likes").add({
        uid: userId,
        createAt: Date.now()
    }).catch(err => { 
        console.log("--- Operation Failure ---")
        return res.status(500).json(err);
    });
};
```

The is the link
[of image the structure of collection and document of the firebase](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HEvYa.png)

**UPDATE**
I check on console of firebase and it return

```
TypeError: db.collection(...).doc(...).collection(...).set is not a function
    at exports.updateLike (/srv/routes/posts.js:47:60)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/srv/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at next (/srv/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:137:13)
    at Route.dispatch (/srv/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:112:3)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/srv/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at /srv/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:281:22
    at param (/srv/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:354:14)
    at param (/srv/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:365:14)
    at param (/srv/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:365:14)
    at Function.process_params (/srv/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:410:3)
```

This the current code. The previous code also return the error as above.

```
exports.updateLike = function (req, res) {

    const postId = req.params.postId;
    const userId = req.params.userId;

    db.collection("posts").doc(postId).collection("likes").set({
        uid: userId,
        createAt: Date.now()
    }).then(post => {
        console.log("--- Operation Success ---")
        return res.status(200).json(post.data());
    }).catch(err => { 
        console.log("--- Operation Failure ---")
        return res.status(500).json(err);
    });
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of this:

```
db.collection("posts").doc(postId).collection("likes").add({ ... })
```

you should write this:

```
db.collection("posts").doc(postId).collection("likes").doc().set({ ... })
```

Comment: I receive error at firebase console stating that this is not a function. I have updated the post with the error.

Comment: Thanks have fixed the error. I overlook and forgot to put a doc behind the collection